# Filtering Dataset based on similar column values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, datatable, dataset

I have a Data in Dataset with 5 columns (ID, col1, col2, col3, col4). I have to filter rows and separate them from main Dataset based on the similar column values. ID column is unique. I have to check the data for the column values in col1, col2, col3 and col4. For example I have 10 records, 5 of them have same column values, 3 of them have same column values other than previous 5 and 2 rows with complete different values. I should now have 4 different datatables with 5, 3, 1 and 1 rows respectively. Theses datatables can be dynamic depending on the data.

Please suggest me the best possible solution.

Comment: You just copy-pasted your task here, or you have started to implement it?

Comment: I started working on it, nothing except looping through the dataset comes on to my mind. I'm expecting better executable code.

Comment: For that you can use the DataView

Answer (score 0):

```
   Dim myDataView As DataView = New DataView('Your Dataset')           
   myDataView.RowFilter = 'Your Serch Values '
```

try this

Comment: Hi Chetan, Thanks for replying. The data is not constant and the column values are also not constant. I have to get all the similar column values into a datatable, so you never know how many databales/dataviews needed.